# Parser PHP - phpQuery

Tags: php, phpquery

I have a task. The table [on this page contains links](http://www.topscolibucuresti.ro/bucuresti). In every link, [for exampple first](http://www.topscolibucuresti.ro/scoala/colegiul-national-gheorghe-lazar), exist one field with email. I must coppy all these emails.

I writing a script using phpQuery.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');
    require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';

    function parseMail($url){
        $file = file_get_contents($url);
        $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
            foreach ($doc->find('#table_top > tbody > tr')as $tempmail{
                $tempmail = pq($tempmail)
                $mail = $tempmail->find("contains('@')");
                }
    }

    function print_arr($arr){
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';
    }

    $url = 'http://www.topscolibucuresti.ro/bucuresti';
    $file = file_get_contents($url);

    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

    foreach($doc->find('#table_top > tbody > tr')as $article){
        $article = pq($article);
        $link = $article->find('a')->attr('href');

        parseMail($link);

        print_arr($mail);
    }
```

The script shows error but I don't understand why.. What I should to do?

Comment: Hey man, I see links, but no email addresses anywhere on the site you provided.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried the problem with another, smaller, web page first? (i.e. have you tried reproducing the problem in isolation?) Have a look at the Help Center to see how to write a great question (stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Jonathon, thanks.. I will look. I did't try in isolation. Do you think it'll be resultative?

Comment: @Yitzhak I need to open every link. And in those pages exist email. For example, first link: http://www.topscolibucuresti.ro/scoala/colegiul-national-gheorghe-lazar

Comment: @engins: what error do you get?

Comment: @Jonathon, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mail' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\OpenServer\domains\parsing\scoli-v1.php on line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you've missed a semi-colon.

```
    foreach ($doc->find('#table_top > tbody > tr')as $tempmail{
        $tempmail = pq($tempmail)
        $mail = $tempmail->find("contains('@')");
```

There should be a semi-colon after `pq($tempmail)`

Comment: Thanks..
But now I get new error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\OpenServer\domains\parsing\scoli-v1.php on line 9

Comment: Your `foreach` doesn't have a close bracket after `$tempmail`